# django dynamic template link dictonary to object fields

Tags: django, templates, object, dictionary, field

I am working on a dynamic template and i hoped to be able to include the last part of it aswell. My problem: I got a x-amount of fields that relate to fields of the object. But when i pass another model object  it should show other fields.

Example: 
model 1 show object name, category, approved
model 2 show object name, attribute,

For the other variable things, i make a dictionary that holds the information, problem is, i dont know how i could link the object fields to it. 
Dictonary send to template:

```
field_map = {'field1': 'Name', 'field2': 'Category', 'field3': 'Approved'}
```

Template:

```
{% if objects|length > 0 %}
<table style="padding: 3px;">
    <tr style=" text-align: center;">
    {% for key, value in field_map %}
        <th>{{ value }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for object in objects %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ object.approved }}</td>
    </tr>
```

But now i want to add the objects fields to the field_map fields.
Cause i will be sending more then 1 object

Hope i explained my question well enough.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to re-implmenet an already solved problem. Please use django-tables2 to render tables in django: https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2

**Update**: To answer OP's comment on how to remove or edit the pagination footer:

*If* you do not want to have pagination to your table then just configure your table passing `paginate=None` to your `RequestConfig` like this:

```
table = TestTable(Test.objects.all())
RequestConfig(request, paginate=None).configure(table)
return render(request, 'test.html', {'table': table})
```

*If* you want to edit the footer yourself then you have to provide a new table rendering template. To do this, you just need to copy the contents of `table.html` from here https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html to your templates directory. You can then modify this file to your requirements, for instance the pagination section is between `{% if table.page %}` and the `{% endif %}` at the end of the file.

Now, after you've created your custom table template you need render your table using this template. If you named your template as mytable.html then just use the following syntax from within your normal templates:

```
{% render_table mytable "mytable.html" %}
```

Comment: Thanks, im going to take a look at it

Comment: No problem - please update your question if you wave an qestions on django-tables2!

Comment: One question, all seems pretty clear, but my table gives always a list at the botem that has a count of my objects, and holds next/previous for when you use pages. How can i remove/edit this?